# Exchange PowerShell ActiveSync stats

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, activesync

I am trying to put a powershell script together to retrieve ActiveSync stats from an Exchange server. My objective is to get a report that includes  stats around ActiveSync devices and some details from the Active Directory accounts associated to the users. To be more specific in addition to the information the script produces I am trying to capture the EmployeeID and businesscategory attributes for each user account. And then output that to a csv.

To be fair, I am not a powershell Wiz and have augmented this script from examples I have found on the net. Any feedback/suggestions will be appreciated.

```
$DCSession = "DC1"
$sess = New-PSSession -computer $DCSession
Invoke-Command -session $sess -script { Import-Module ActiveDirectory }
Import-PSSession -session $sess -module ActiveDirectory
$ASUser = Get-CASMailbox -Filter {HasActiveSyncDevicePartnership -eq $True -and DisplayName -notlike "CAS_{*"} 
$ACT = Get-ADUser -ID $ASUser.SAMAccountName -Properties EmployeeID, BusinessCategory
$ASUser | ForEach {$Name = $_.Name; $EMail = $_.PrimarySMTPAddress; $Device = Get-    ActiveSyncDeviceStatistics -Mailbox $_.identity; $Device | ForEach {Write-Host $Name, $Email,         $ACT.EmployeeID, $ACT.BusinessCategory, $_.devicemodel, $_.devicephonenumber, $_.deviceid, $_.FirstSyncTime, $_.LastSuccessSync} } 

Remove-PSSession $sess`
```

Comment: You dont really have a question. What is wrong or not working as intended

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. Like I mentioned in my note above, the script gets all the ActiveSync related information just fine, but it isnt pulling the AD information (EmployeeID,BusinessCategory) so I am wondering if someone can point out my mistake. Other I want to capture the output in a CSV file which I can't seem to be able to do with the band aid of a script before you so suggestions around how to export the output into a CSV will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this information output to screen? It looks like everything you are asking for is there on the console screen? Just need to fix the output method and it should go to csv nicely.

Comment: You are right, it is writing to the host console .. when I try to do an Export-CSV I get SL's of errors and then there are the missing AD fields.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is very similar to Matt's, I just used Add-Member to work with the existing objects rather than doing it in the Select cmdlet. This also leaves you with the `$Devices` array so you can work with them later if you need to.

Basically for each device of each person it adds the person's Name, Email Address, EmployeeID, and BusinessCategory to the device's object, and then passes that through on the last Add-Member creating an array of device objects that you can work with. It also outputs to a CSV for you.

```
$DCSession = "DC1"
$sess = New-PSSession -computer $DCSession
Invoke-Command -session $sess -script { Import-Module ActiveDirectory }
Import-PSSession -session $sess -module ActiveDirectory
$ASUser = Get-CASMailbox -Filter {HasActiveSyncDevicePartnership -eq $True -and DisplayName -notlike "CAS_{*"} 

$Devices = ForEach($User in $ASUser) {
    $ACT = Get-ADUser -ID $User.SAMAccountName -Properties EmployeeID, BusinessCategory
    Get-ActiveSyncDeviceStatistics -Mailbox $_.identity | ForEach{
        Add-Member -InputObject $_ -NotePropertyName 'EmployeeID' -NotePropertyValue $ACT.EmployeeID
        Add-Member -InputObject $_ -NotePropertyName 'BusinessCategory' -NotePropertyValue $ACT.BusinessCategory
        Add-Member -InputObject $_ -NotePropertyName 'Name' -NotePropertyValue $User.Name
        Add-Member -InputObject $_ -NotePropertyName 'Email' -NotePropertyValue $User.PrimarySMTPAddress -PassThru
    }
} 

$Devices | Select Name,Email,EmployeeID,BusinessCategory,DeviceModel,DevicePhoneNumber,DeviceID,FirstSyncTime,LastSyncTime | Export-CSV "C:\Path\To\Export.CSV" -NoTypeInformation

Remove-PSSession $sess
```

Comment: Sure missed you :}. If this works just use this one.

Comment: Thakss Madtech .. that didnt work either .. when I do .. $ASUser = Get-CASMailbox -Filter {HasActiveSyncDevicePartnership -eq $True -and DisplayName -notlike "CAS_{*"}  .. and then $ASUsers  | Select SamAccountName .. the output is empty

Comment: That tells me there's something wrong with your filter then, or that `SamAccountName` is not a property of the object returned by `Get-CASMailbox`

Comment: I just checked and that cmdlet returns a [CASMailbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.data.directory.management.casmailbox_members(v=exchg.150).aspx) object, which does have a SamAccountName property. If you simply run `Get-CASMailbox -Filter {HasActiveSyncDevicePartnership -eq $True -and DisplayName -notlike "CAS_{*"}` does it return anything?

Comment: But it is .. :( ... amongst others .. EmailAddresses
LegacyExchangeDN
LinkedMasterAccount
PrimarySmtpAddress
ProtocolSettings
SamAccountName
ServerLegacyDN

Comment: And I do see the account names when I get .. $ASUser | Select SamAccountName

Comment: I just noticed, you are assigning `$ASUser = ` and then run `$ASUsers | Select samAccountName` ...you added an **s** to the variable name on that second command.

Comment: Just verified the script I am working on .. no extra "s"

Comment: Just verified the script I am working on .. no extra "s". It looks like the identify field is coming out with too much information. Like when I run $ASUser | Select $_.identity .. I get these columns .. Name ActiveSyncEnabled OWAEnabled        PopEnabled ImapEnabled MapiEnabled .. and the name field contisn the user name in the FirstName LastName format.

Comment: I just fixed an error in my code (`$_` where `$User` should have been). Try it again and let me know if it works better for you. If you get an error please reference the part of the code provided that gives an error.

Comment: From what I can tell, the line 5 of the script is not pulling the information I need (SAMAccountName) which that is a property available. how I know this, when I run that line in particular and try to find the use SAMAccountName by doing $ASUser.SAMAccountName the output is blank,

Comment: Is it giving any results at all? If not then I'd say remove the -filter and see if that is the problem

Comment: So yes, when I look at the output of $ASUser there is information collected, but the SAMAccountName filed is not one of them. Now I will imagine if I do $ASUser = Get-CASMailbox -Filter {HasActiveSyncDevicePartnership -eq $True -and DisplayName -notlike "CAS_{*"}  with an FL at the end it will collect and store all properties of each user which i confirmed by doing $ASUser but when I do $ASUser.SAMAccountName after that the output is empty.

Comment: No, piping to Format-List (which is what FL is short for) will not make the Get-CASMailbox cmdlet to magically collect additional information.

Comment: I think at this point it would be good to know what you *are* getting back from Get-CASMailbox. I don't have access to that cmdlet personally.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after reading the comments the issue is that you are having issues outputting to csv. `Export-CSV` will take all output and write it to a csv file. The two issues you have there are

1. You are writing the data to the shell so there is no output to pipe
2. `Export-Csv` prefers objects to output to file. `Add-Content` might work in this case.

---

```
$ASUser = Get-CASMailbox -Filter {HasActiveSyncDevicePartnership -eq $True -and DisplayName -notlike "CAS_*"}
$ACT = Get-ADUser -ID $ASUser.SAMAccountName -Properties EmployeeID, BusinessCategory
$ASUser | ForEach {
    $Name = $_.Name
    $EMail = $_.PrimarySMTPAddress

    $Device = Get-ActiveSyncDeviceStatistics -Mailbox $_.identity
    $Device | Select-Object @{n="Name";e={$Name}},
                @{n="Email";e={$Email}},
                @{n="EmployeeID";e={$ACT.EmployeeID}},
                @{n="BusinessCategory";e={$ACT.BusinessCategory}},
                devicemodel,devicephonenumber,deviceid,FirstSyncTime,LastSuccessSync
} | Export-CSV -Path "C:\temp\File.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

The above code was meant to replace the line starting with `$ASUser=` up until the Remove session. What this does is output an array of objects to `Export-CSV`. Since the data is from multiple objects we collect it all in a big `Select-Object`.

The code that looks like `@{n=Email;e={$Email}}` is short form for `@{Name=Email;Expression={$Email}}` which is known as a calculated property. We use that since employee data is not part of the `Get-ActiveSyncDeviceStatistics` cmdlet. *Pretty* sure this works.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Matt and your effort in putting the example together. However I tried but am getting some errors. Like:The term 'Name' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelli
ng of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At H:\scrap\TS.ps1:10 char:37
+     $Device | Select-Object @{n=Name <<<< ;e={$Name}},
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Name:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: and ... Get-ActiveSyncDeviceStatistics : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Mailbox'. The argument is null or empty. Supply
 an argument that is not null or empty and then try the command again.
At H:\scrap\TS.ps1:9 char:54
+     $Device = Get-ActiveSyncDeviceStatistics -Mailbox <<<<  $_.identity
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-ActiveSyncDeviceStatistics], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Tasks.GetMobileDeviceStat
   istics

Comment: part of that is me not quoting strings....thats been fixed. Checking the other error.

Comment: If `$_.identity` is null what I have done should not have changed that.

Comment: Looks like I am dong something wrong too, here is what I have that is setting those:

Comment: $ASUser = Get-CASMailbox -Filter {HasActiveSyncDevicePartnership -eq $True -and DisplayName -notlike "CAS_{*"} 
    $ACT = Get-ADUser -ID $ASUser.SAMAccountName -Properties EmployeeID, BusinessCategory

Comment: When I do .. $ASUser = Get-CASMailbox -ID SomeUser it pulls the identity if I use the other it doesnt.

Comment: @RXA I can see a syntax error in there. Check out the updated answer. Fixed that line that I think was wrong.

Comment: The identity is still coming out empty, I tried to play around with that line in particular again if I pull just one user it gets it but if I drop the masses in the array it doesn't. I wonder if I have to specifically call that property out in: $ASUser = Get-CASMailbox -Filter {HasActiveSyncDevicePartnership -eq $True -and DisplayName -notlike "CAS_*"}

Comment: What is the output of this `$ASUser | Select Identity`? Is there gaps? I dont have any issue

Comment: Yes there are spaces, so the output is lie: domain.com/OU 1/Child OU1/Child OU2/Some OU Name/User_FirstName User_LastName .. for what it is worth I have tried adding quotes around $ASUser.SamAccountName but that didnt do the trick. And also, in the script we are asking for users SAMAccountName so I'd imagine this I should be looking for $ASUser | SAMAccountName .. which is formatted right in the samaccount form.

Comment: Sorry... I wasnt specific. I meant line gaps not spaces like there were some nulls in the ouputs. Since it is in the variable it should not need to be quoted in _this_ case. I will test your code more. So far though I do not get errors. Are you in the ISE? perhaps close and reopen your session to be sure. @RXA

Comment: Nope, no gaps. I am using ISE but on a different machine, the script is running on a different machine in PS.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this Matt, but so far no dice.